# Duplicates removal with foldl

Tags: list, haskell, duplicates, fold

I'm trying to write my implementation of `remdps`, function, which removes nearest duplicates in a list. For example: `"aaabbbsscaa"` should became `"absca"`. I have to use `foldl`. Here is my attempt:

```
helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
helper [] ele = [ele]
helper newlist ele = if tail newlist /= ele then newlist:ele
    else newlist

remdps :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
remdps list = foldl helper [] list

main = putStrLn (show (remdps "aabssscdddeaffff"))
```

And the error:

```
4.hs:4:41:
    Could not deduce (a ~ [a])
    from the context (Eq a)
      bound by the type signature for helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
      at 4.hs:2:11-33
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
          at 4.hs:2:11
    In the second argument of `(/=)', namely `ele'
    In the expression: tail newlist /= ele
    In the expression:
      if tail newlist /= ele then newlist : ele else newlist

4.hs:4:50:
    Could not deduce (a ~ [a])
    from the context (Eq a)
      bound by the type signature for helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
      at 4.hs:2:11-33
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
          at 4.hs:2:11
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `newlist'
    In the expression: newlist : ele
    In the expression:
      if tail newlist /= ele then newlist : ele else newlist

4.hs:4:58:
    Could not deduce (a ~ [a])
    from the context (Eq a)
      bound by the type signature for helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
      at 4.hs:2:11-33
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
          at 4.hs:2:11
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `ele'
    In the expression: newlist : ele
    In the expression:
      if tail newlist /= ele then newlist : ele else newlist
fish: Unknown command './4'
ghc 4.hs; and ./4
```

The question is always the same:). What's wrong?

//edit

OK, I have a working code. It uses `reverse` and `++`, so it's very ugly:).

```
helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
helper [] ele = [ele]
helper newlist ele = if head (reverse newlist) /= ele then newlist ++ [ele]
    else newlist

remdps :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
remdps list = foldl helper [] list

main = putStrLn (show (remdps "aabssscdddeaffff"))
```

Comment: You're trying to use `==` to compare an `a` with a `[a]`, and you're trying to use `:` to construct a list whose head is of type `[a]` and whose tail is of type `a`.  Not gonna work.

Comment: Additionally, do you really have to use `foldl`? `foldl` gives you left context, `foldr` gives you right context, but this problem needs *both* types of context: left context to decide whether to keep a list element, and right context to cons elements on front of the result list.  If it's really `foldl` only, you're going to have to build the result in reverse order and then reverse it at the end—but then your function doesn't work for infinite lists.

Comment: Isn't tail and head always of type `a`? I thought that `newlist` is type of `[a]`, `ele` is type of `a` and `tail newlist` is type of `a`.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I thought `tail` returns the last element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're probably trying to do is this:

```
helper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
helper [] ele = [ele]
helper newlist ele = if last newlist /= ele then newlist ++ [ele]
    else newlist
```

The changes:

- `:` works only in one way: on the left is the head of the list (type `a`), on the right the tail (type `[a]`). It's sometimes also called "cons". What you want to do is called "snoc": on its right is the last element of the list (type `a`), and on the left the initial part (type `[a]`).

  "snoc" doesn't exist in the Prelude, so instead, you just write it in a different way: `newlist ++ [ele]`. (Compare this to `x : xs == [x] ++ xs`.)
- `tail newlist == ele` becomes `last newlist == ele`. `tail` gets the list without its head, but you want to compare the last element of `newlist`. For that purpose, you have `last`. (By the way, to get the initial part of a list, you can use `init`.)

<strike>Note that you've also swapped the branches of your if-statement, leaving you with `aaa` as the answer.</strike> -edit- I see that you've updated that now ;)

---

Also note that this is a very slow approach. Every "snoc" and `last` will take longer as the answer of `remdps` grows, because Prelude lists are much better at "cons" and `head`. Try rewriting the function so that it uses "cons" instead. Hint: you'll need `reverse` at some point.

Furthermore, this function will not work when used with infinite lists, because of the way `foldl` works. It might be an interesting exercise to rewrite this function to use `foldr` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The type annotation of helper suggest that  **ele** is of **type a**
And you do the following test **(tail(newlist) == ele)**, but tail if of **type [a]**

You cannot compare two value if different type.

This is not the only error.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the docs for [Data.List](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html). Specifically for `tail` you'll see that the type is `[a] -> [a]`, so obviously it doesn't return the last element of the list as one might think.

If you're looking to get a single element of out of a list (the last one) you need something with type `[a] -> a`. The power of haskell comes from the fact that this information is almost enough to find the right function.

Just [Hoogle it!](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5ba%5d+-%3E+a)

P.S. As a side note - this approach is quite slow, as mentioned in Tinctorius' answer

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my second comment, though this doesn't answer your question as posed, I would very much not use `foldl` to do this.  Back in my Scheme days I'd solve it with this pet `kfoldr` function of mine, which I've translated to Haskell here:

```
-- |  A special fold that gives you both left and right context at each right
-- fold step.  See the example below.
kfoldr :: (l -> a -> l) -> l -> (l -> a -> r -> r) -> (l -> r) -> [a] -> r
kfoldr advance left combine seedRight [] = seedRight left
kfoldr advance left combine seedRight (x:xs) = combine left x (subfold xs)
where subfold = let newLeft = advance left x 
                in newLeft `seq` kfoldr advance newLeft combine seedRight


removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
removeDuplicates = kfoldr advance Nothing step (const [])
    where 
      -- advance is the left context generator, which in this case just 
      -- produces the previous element at each position.
      advance _ x = Just x
      -- step's three arguments in this case are:
      --   (a) the element to the left of current
      --   (b) the current element
      --   (c) the solution for the rest of the list
      step Nothing x xs = x:xs
      step (Just x') x xs
           | x == x' = xs
           | otherwise = x:xs
```

Haskell's `Data.List` library has `mapAccumL` and `mapAccumR` which are similar but they map instead of folding. There's also the intimately related `scanl` and `scanr`, which can probably be used to implement `kfoldr` (but I haven't bothered to try).

Comment: Isn't that way too complicated? `let nodup x yys@(y:_) | x == y = yys; nodup x zs = x:zs in foldr nodup "" "aaaabbbbsssssccccaaaa"`.

Comment: Oh, wow, yeah. I somehow got stuck on the idea of determining duplication by looking at the left, and failed to notice you can do it by looking right. I feel like the king of rocket surgeons now...

Comment: I have to remember "king of rocket surgeons", that's brilliant.